# Comparing Firebase database with phone contact list

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an android chatting app. I am trying to compare phone contact list with [firebase-database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I61MT.jpg) "phone" that is in "Users" child. I am trying to get key value of "phone" with query and conpared with phone contact list and put it in [user](https://pastebin.com/jRNkaQaw) model that can fetch information from the database for chatlist.

Here is my code

```
final DatabaseReference mUserDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
            Query query = mUserDB.orderByChild("phone").equalTo(mContact.getPhone());
            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        String phone = "",
                                name = "";

                        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            dataSnapshot.getKey();

                            if (childSnapshot.child("phone").getValue() != null) {
                                phone = childSnapshot.child("phone").getValue().toString();
                            }
                            if (childSnapshot.child("username").getValue() != null) {
                                name = childSnapshot.child("username").getValue().toString();
                            }
                            UserObject mUser = new UserObject(childSnapshot.getKey(), name, phone);
                            userList.add(mUser);

                                for (UserObject mContactIterator : contactList) {
                                    if (mContactIterator.getPhone().equals(mUser.getPhone())) {

                                            mUsers.clear();
                      //I think User user can not get the value 
                                            User user = childSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                                            mUsers.add(user);
                                            final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                                            if (!user.getId().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
                                                mUsers.add(user);
                                            }


                                        }
                                        userAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(), mUsers, false);
                                        recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);


                                    }
                                }
                            }




                }
```

[Firebase database Image](https://pastebin.com/jRNkaQaw)

I think in here does not work correctly

```
if (!user.getId().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
                                                mUsers.add(user);
                                            }
```

The chatlist need to show users that have in contact list but the chatlist is an empty result
& I saw previously this related StackOverflow  question but it does not work for me

Comment: Please edit your question to be more specific, what is not working the Firebase query or the phone contacts query? Have you ask permission for the devices contacts?

Comment: yes permission granted and i am using this code in my User Fragment .I  had to fetch all contact list and also add country code  in contact number to compare with  my firebase "phone" child number that is inserted  for phone authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved and my code is working ,Thanks

```
final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
final DatabaseReference mUserDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");  
  Query query = mUserDB.orderByChild("phone").equalTo(mContact.getPhone());
            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        String phone = "";

                        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            dataSnapshot.getKey();

                            if (childSnapshot.child("phone").getValue() != null) {
                                phone = childSnapshot.child("phone").getValue().toString();
                            }


                            UserObject mUser = new UserObject(childSnapshot.getKey(), "", phone);
                            userList.add(mUser);



                                            mUsers.clear();
                      //I think User user can not get the value 
                                            User user = childSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                                            mUsers.add(user);

                                            if (!user.getId().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
                                                mUsers.add(user);
                                            }
```